# How can I tie my application to specific hardware?

Tags: c#, .net, hardware, wmi

I have a C# .NET app. This application is tightly coupled to a piece of hardware. Think ATM, drive up kiosk kinda thing. I want a way for my application to assure it is being run on our hardware. Our initial plan was to get the serial number of the CPU, OS, HD, or other hardware with WMI, digitally sign that, and ship that signature with the software. The application would then have the public key in it to verify the signature. Is there a better way to do this?

**Update 1**

We dont want a dongle or a hasp. Nothing external to the system.

Comment: You realize that you will probably put more money amd effort into preventing it from other hardware than it's worth.  Anyone that really want to run the software without your signing key can just remove your protections.  Also you are now limiting your customers if they ever need to quickly fix the system.

Comment: It all depends on the situation. We have applications that are shipped with very specific hardware, not a computer but embedded hardware that supports .NET The hardware and software come as a packaged deal and that is what they buy from us. The customer doesn't want to perform maintenance, that's why they have contracts and SLA's with us... There are are certainly good reasons to do this, but not for most apps that's true.... That said, unless you control every aspect, from chip development to software, you can never fully protect everything. (Which is why apple controls the chips as well)

Comment: http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm has tools that will help you create hardware locking, but don't use that as the only method... the more popular an obfuscation/lock-in tool gets, the more effort people put into hacking it. And make sure you have solid legal agreements with the customer, that's the most important thing!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would have a semi-safe system. It can prevent running on different hardware. It will also prevent some forms of maintenance of that hardware.

It will, as usual, not prevent anyone from decompiling and changing your software.

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar for software licensing by signing an XML file, although ours isn't tied to any hardware. The same concept applies. It works well.

You will also need to protect your .NET code using some kind of obfuscation tool, we use [{smartassembly}](http://www.smartassembly.com/) but there are several others out there.

Keep in mind that no matter what you do, given enough time and resources, someone can bypass it.

That doesn't mean you should not protect your intellectual property, but there is a point where you get diminishing returns and cause more trouble to you and your customers that it's worth.

Comment: No obfuscation tool is perfect. Native code can even be reverse engineered these days. For every obfuscation/protection tool made, there is a way found around it.