# How to get serial number for all of computer's hardware via C#.Net?

Tags: c#, numbers, wmi, hardware, serial-number

How to get serial number for all of computer's hardware via C#.Net? Like Mouse, Keyboard, Speaker, Printer and so on?

And is it possible to get name of company and model of them?

thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to fast get Hardware-ID in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333149/how-to-fast-get-hardware-id-in-c).

Comment: What do you mean by "Serial Number"?

Comment: Your best bet is to use WMI which I don't think has that information for _all_ of the computer's hardware (e.g. a generic PS/2 keyboard and mouse typically won't share that information with their host).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tie my application to specific hardware?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574859/how-can-i-tie-my-application-to-specific-hardware)

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Is it really a dupe? Sure they _could_ have similar answers though this one actually defines a (albeit thin) level of requirements and the other is (for all intents and purposes) about limiting an application to run on a single PC.

Comment: @M.Babcock - right, it isn't a very close dupe.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - (I liked your previous comment better) Won't flagging the wrong duplicate cause the "dupe consolidation mechanism" to merge invalid answers?

Comment: see these: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28678/Generating-Unique-Key-Finger-Print-for-a-Computer

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18522/Finger-Print-Class

Answer (score 0):

[This thread in MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/a97b65ff-22f2-46aa-b787-6403effdd78c/) is what you looking for.

for example:

```
string processor = RunQuery("Processor", "ProcessorId");
```